# Runtime error in a C program. ''Windows is trying to find a solution''

Tags: c

I wanted to share a problem that I have been facing many times...

See this code that I have written:

```
int main(){
    /*main method*/
    char original[10];
    char c;
    int i;

    for(i=0; (c=getchar())!=EOF;i++){           
        original[i]=c;
    }
    printf(totalElements(original));



}

int totalElements(char a[]){
    char c;
    int i=0;

    while((c=a[i])!='\0'){
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

This is a code that will determine the total numbers of characters(elements) in the input. For eg: The input 'CAT' has 3 characters, so it will print 3.

But, when I run this code, after a few seconds a prompt comes that it has stopped working and windows is trying to find a solution.....

Can someone tell me what is the problem?

And not only this time, but I have faced this problem many times..

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Add `original[i] = '\0'` before `printf(totalElements(original));`. Also, you can add `if( i == 8 ) { i++; break; }` in the loop just after `original[i]=c;` to prevent buffer overflows.

Comment: `totalElements` returns `int`, so what do you expect `printf(totalElements(original));` do?

Comment: And `char c;` should be `int c;`.

Comment: @YuHao, shoudn't  `printf(totalElements(original));` print the value?

Comment: @Siddhant "_shoudn't `printf(totalElements(original));` print the value?_" -- No. `printf` expects a string literal(`const char*` or `"..."`) as its first argument, not an `int`. The correct way would be to use `printf("%d", totalElements(original));`.

Comment: Note: It is easier to use `strlen()` from `string.h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't adding the string terminator character to the end of your string.

```
int main(){
    /*main method*/
    char original[10];
    int c;
    int i;

    for(i=0;i < 9 && (c=getchar())!=EOF;i++){           
        original[i]=c;
    }
    original[i] = '\0';
    printf("%d\n", totalElements(original));

    return 0;

}

int totalElements(char a[]){
    char c;
    int i=0;

    while((c=a[i])!='\0'){
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}
```

And also your printf is incorrect.

Comment: Oh I forgot to add that... thnx @Viktor Simkó

Comment: you answer is partial. what happens if I enter 20 chacacters?

Comment: @DavidHaim, it is just a test program... not an original one... I completely agree to your statement... And I am just a IX grade student.. I make test programs to check my skills.... When I will write a full working code, I will definitely keep these things in mind

Answer (score 1):

A Windows error dialog such as "Windows is trying to find a solution" after stopping a program indicates that there is a defect in the application being run that has caused it to abnormally terminate.

If you are getting this many times it is because the program(s) you are writing or using have defects in them which are causing errors when run.

This error message is to inform the user of the application that the application has abnormally terminated and that Windows is checking the Microsoft abnormal termination database to see if this problem has been documented. Since these are applications you are writing yourself rather than a Microsoft or other vendor's application, the chances of Windows finding a solution is fairly slim.

This article, [Disable "Windows is checking for a solution to the problem..." prompt after a program hangs up](http://www.techspot.com/community/topics/disable-windows-is-checking-for-a-solution-to-the-problem-prompt-after-a-program-hangs-up.193376/) provides a procedure for disabling this message. The basic procedure is to go to the "Change Action Center settings" and change the setting for "Problem reporting settings".